# What are these parts? (better photos)

Tags: components, identification

I have salvaged some parts that I can't identify myself. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what they are called so I can look them up.

I took some better photos of the first 3 parts, and added a 7th at the bottom.  Sorry about #3, but it is convex from all sides, and I don't have a light diffusor (yet).

[image: part 1 better]1:
[image: 1]

[image: part 2 better]2:
[image: 2]

[image]3:
[image: 3]

4:
[image: 4]

5:
[image: 5]

6:
[image: 6]

[image: part 7]

Sorry for the low quality of the photos.  I'll get better with more experience with my camera.

Comment: My guess, in order from top to bottom: Unknown; some kind of diode; 4MHz ceramic resonator; Unknown; Unknown; 1KV MOV, or 1KV rated 10pf ceramic capacitor.  Most of them look like they come from overload protection circuitry - often seen on telephony interfaces, like ADSL.

Comment: Could the first one be an inductor?

Comment: My votes: 1. inductor; 2. diode, or if the outer bands are equally wide it may be a DIAC; 3. 4MHz resonator; 4. diode (partial partnumber BYV); 5. filter or resonator; 6. capacitor; Where did you find them?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the first one is a light detector of some sort.

From the size of its leads, the second one looks like a Zener diode, but for sure it's a diode of some kind.

The third one is a 4.0 MHz ceramic resonator with internal caps for use in a Pierce oscillator.

From the "BYV" legend on the fourth one, it's a high-speed rectifier of some sort. The rest of the legend would probably single it out.

The fifth one, a transistor? a dual diode?  ???

The sixth one is a 10pF 1kV ceramic capacitor

Views showing more legending would be helpful.

Comment: I'd rather say the 5th is a filter too because it looks moulded.